# Flutter Desktop: Cannot find device on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, desktop

I want to activate with `flutter config --enable-macos-desktop`, after execution the value is set to true but (Unavailable).

[image: Error message]

The problem is that I also can not see my device in `flutter devices`. So my question is do you know why it is Unavailable and if it is possible to write currently desktop apps for macOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you can verify what is available and set your environment properly:

```
$ flutter config
....
.... 
Settings:
  enable-macos-desktop: true (Unavailable)

$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter devices

No devices detected.
```

Now if you will change it to master

```
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter devices

Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine aaf9e79f1d29e128ad5d3beaad1bf4dd0074c470...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  221M  100  221M    0     0  27.2M      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 27.7M
Building flutter tool...
Downloading package sky_engine...                                   0.5s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                            1.0s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                    0.8s
Downloading darwin-x64 tools...                                     1.6s
Downloading darwin-x64/font-subset tools...                         0.6s
1 connected device:

macOS • macOS • darwin-x64 • Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287

$ flutter devices                                                                                                                                
1 connected device:

macOS • macOS • darwin-x64 • Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287

$ flutter config

....
....
Settings:
  enable-macos-desktop: true
```

Comment: @MyracleDesign's answer combined with these steps: Did this on macOS 11.0 "Big Sur" beta, fixed it right up. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I found the problem. To make some settings work you have to be on a specific flutter channel. I was on the dev channel of flutter and therefore the configurations did not work.

I changed now to flutter master and it worked well.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

Comment: This answer and @AvkashChauhan's combined offer explanation + steps.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can verify what is available and set your environment properly:

```
$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter devices

No devices detected.
```

Now if you will change it to master

```
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter devices

Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine aaf9e79f1d29e128ad5d3beaad1bf4dd0074c470...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  221M  100  221M    0     0  27.2M      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 27.7M
Building flutter tool...
Downloading package sky_engine...                                   0.5s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                            1.0s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                    0.8s
Downloading darwin-x64 tools...                                     1.6s
Downloading darwin-x64/font-subset tools...                         0.6s
1 connected device:

macOS • macOS • darwin-x64 • Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287

$ flutter devices                                                                                                                                
1 connected device:

macOS • macOS • darwin-x64 • Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287

$ flutter config

....
....
Settings:
  enable-macos-desktop: true
```

Comment: This answer appears to be a duplicate of your own answer, consider combining them?